# After removing a file with special characters in filename it is still listed

Tags: nautilus, special-characters, filename

I have removed a file with a special character in its file-name by placing it in the Trash can using Nautilus. Yet, it is still listed using "ls -la" giving something like:

-????????? ? ? ? ? ? "file-name with special character"

What I already tried to do is to remove it with "rm". Then it gives:

rm: cannot remove `file-name with special character': No such file or directory

How can I remove it such that it is now really removed and not shown in "ls"?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it remove it based on it's inode number. An inode is an index number that's used by the file system instead of the filename to lookup file information (permissions etc). In a terminal, in the directory of the problematic file, run `ls -i` that'll give you something similar to the following:

```
$ ls -i
7995865 a  7995866 b  7995867 c
```

Then to remove it you can use `find`, and `rm`

```
$ find . -inum 7995866 -exec rm -f {} \;
$ ls -i
7995865 a  7995867 c
```

Comment: Caution - this can sometimes be a warning sign of impending disk failure. I suggest you run smartmontools to test your disk and , from a live USB, fsck ;)

Comment: Thanks, AJefferiss. I have tried exactly that: find its inode and remove it in the way you suggest. It then says that there is no such file or directory. It seems as if the file is really "removed" but yet it still appears in "ls".

Comment: Thanks bodhi.zazen. You may be right. Some disk failure may also possibly explain why sometimes the file is listed with only question marks and sometimes with info such as inode, rwx information, size, creation date, etc.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like @bodhi.zazen is right about disk failure, I thought maybe some encoding issue was the cause of the `???..`. If you've not already, I'd backup any important data on the drive then check the disk like bodhi.zazen suggested.